# NameError: name 'np' is not defined

Tags: jupyter-notebook, python-import, nameerror

I try to import the following functions:

```
import numpy as np
def load_labels(path):
   y = np.load(path)
   return y

def print_sentence():
   print("hi")
```

from a Jupyter notebook, with name "save_load" into another Jupyter notebook with the following code:

```
!pip install import-ipynb
import import_ipynb
import save_load
from save_load import load_labels, print_sentence
```

The function `print_sentence` works fine in the notebook, but with the function `load_labels` I receive the following error:

NameError: name 'np' is not defined

What could be the reason for this error? I've imported `numpy as np` in both notebooks.

Answer (score 0):

In "save_load" instead of `import numpy as np` try `import numpy`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

import numpy as np
or
from numpy import *

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was fixing my codes on VScode. Try saving the file. Then run it again.